# Building JavaFx8 Jar does not contain Gluon Charm libraries

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I have tried to build a JavaFx8 jar file in IntelliJ using the Gluon libraries.  The jar is built but once I try to access a controller that requires a Gluon charm library the application crashes.  We are using: 
com.gluonhq:charm-down-desktop:1.0.0.

I am building using the Gradle build that is included in the project.  See attached.

[image: build task]

Here is the stack trace:

```
Mar 31, 2016 12:22:29 PM TimeShiftGluon.Native.NativePlatformFactory getPlatform
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gluonhq/charm/down/common/JavaFXPlatform
    at TimeShiftGluon.Native.NativePlatformFactory.getSQliteDriver(NativePlatformFactory.java:48)
    at TimeShiftGluon.Native.NativePlatformFactory.getPlatform(NativePlatformFactory.java:18)
    at TimeShiftGluon.TimeShift_View.Main.setDeviceType(Main.java:748)
    at TimeShiftGluon.TimeShift_View.Main.start(Main.java:364)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.down.common.JavaFXPlatform
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cometd/client/transport/ClientTransport
    at TimeShiftGluon.TimeShift_View.Main.start(Main.java:366)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cometd.client.transport.ClientTransport
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more

Thanks for your help.
```

Here is our build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'TimeShiftGluon.TimeShift_View.Main'

ext.CHARM_DOWN_VERSION = "1.0.0"


dependencies{
    compile "com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"

    // CometD deps
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:9.2.14.v20151106'
    compile 'org.cometd.java:cometd-websocket-jetty:2.9.1'
    compile 'org.cometd.java:cometd-java-websocket-jetty-client:3.0.3'

    desktopRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-desktop:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
    desktopRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.11.2'

    desktopRuntime 'org.cometd.java:cometd-java-client:3.0.9'

    androidRuntime 'org.cometd.java:cometd-java-client:3.0.9'

    androidRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-android:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'

    iosRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-ios:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"

}

jfxmobile {
     android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = '/Applications/Old Apps/Android Studio.app/sdk'

    }
    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = [ 'com.gluonhq.**.*' ]
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}

task runAsTablet(dependsOn: jar, type: JavaExec, group: "Run") {
    main = mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.desktop.runtimeClasspath
    jvmArgs "-Dcharm-desktop-form=tablet"
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `build.gradle` file? If you are still using charm 1.0.0 dependencies I suggest you update to the latest Gluon plugin for IntelliJ (2.2.0).

Comment: Sure.  I just posted the build.gradle file.  We are using 1.0.0

Comment: You'll either need to add the Gluon project as a runtime dependency. Or you will need to create a fat jar, using something like [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly).

Comment: Upgrading to the plugin 2.2.0 worked. But we are also having a crash with CometD.  Is CometD supported by Gluon?

Comment: I haven't tested it. Maybe you can use Tyrus? Have a look at this [project](https://github.com/TRIPJavaFXClientBraintrust/TRIPfx)